# Subtract a number from an value shown from an echo statement

Tags: php, jquery, magento

I am using this code to echo a number

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getFinalPrice(),true,false); ?>
```

The output looks something like $1850.00

What I want to do is instantly subtract $720.00 from the amount shown.

Is it better to do it with php or with jquery? I am imagining the code will be really simple... please show me:

Comment: Please read the documentation. Alternatively, do `var_dump( $_product->getFinalPrice() );`. I suspect that is an int?

Comment: did you even read the requirement to subtract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you purely want to echo the lower value, then;

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency(($_product->getFinalPrice()-720),true,false); ?>
```

The products price will still be $1850 if it's added to the basket though.

Comment: Thanks man! I knew it was super simple, I was just putting my -720 in the wrong place! It's ok I dont want it ubtracted in the cart, we are just showing a tooltip of what the price could be if cash back is applied. Thanks again for your help.